# Mockito - Verify a method is called twice with two different params

Tags: java, mockito

**I have to verify the behavior on the following method:**

```
public void saveRequestAndResponse(request, response, additionalInfo) {
    // some processing with additionalInfo
    dao.save(request);
    dao.save(response);
}
```

**In my test class:**

```
ArgumentCaptor<com.ws.Request> request = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(com.ws.Request.class);
Mockito.verify(dao, Mockito.times(1)).save(request.capture());

ArgumentCaptor<com.ws.Response> response = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(com.ws.Response.class);
Mockito.verify(dao, Mockito.times(1)).save(response.capture());
```

**And the DAO method:**

```
@Transactional
Public <T> T save(final T it) {
    saveOrUpdate(it);
}
```

**Error received:**

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations: 
dao.save(<Capturing argument>);
Wanted 1 time:
-> at com.ws.testclass(TestClass.java:296)
But was 2 times:
-> at com.ws.mainclass.lambda$saveRequestAndResponse$78(MainClass.java:200)
-> at com.ws.mainclass.saveRequestAndResponse(MainClass.java:205)
```

The save() method in my DAO class uses the type parameter T.

How do I verify two invocations on `dao.save(type)` method with two different types such as Request and Response?

Comment: Hi, do you need the value in each object (request, response)? because if it's not the case you can use `Mockito.verify(dao, Mockito.times(2)).save(Mockito.any());`

Comment: @MarcoPens that is correct, I want to validate the value at each invocation:  save(request) and save(response).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
ArgumentCaptor<Object> parameters = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Object.class);
Mockito.verify(dao, Mockito.times(2)).save(parameters.capture());
List<Object> values= parameters.getAllValues();
com.ws.Request req= (com.ws.Request) values.get(0);
com.ws.Response res= (com.ws.Respons) values.get(1);
//Validations
```

Comment: This may work, but it really obfuscates the intent, and is an abuse of what capture is meant to do.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is [in order verification](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.9/org/mockito/Mockito.html#in_order_verification). From the documentation:

```
// A. Single mock whose methods must be invoked in a particular order
 List singleMock = mock(List.class);

 //using a single mock
 singleMock.add("was added first");
 singleMock.add("was added second");

 //create an inOrder verifier for a single mock
 InOrder inOrder = inOrder(singleMock);

 //following will make sure that add is first called with "was added first, then with "was added second"
 inOrder.verify(singleMock).add("was added first");
 inOrder.verify(singleMock).add("was added second");
```

Comment: This is another way to do that, and if your need to do this with object you need to implement a `hashCode` and `equals` methods it's not that simple if you need to check something particular in to object